# How to convert military time to MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:s tt in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a column from temporary table `DateCreated` which has an output of `2/23/2015 17:28` but I want to convert it to `2/23/2015 5:28 PM`.

My current code looks like this:

```
SELECT t1.DateCreated 
FROM #tempTable t1
```

Comment: Have you tried Cast or Convert?  What problem are you having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `1` and `100` style in `convert function`

```
select convert(varchar(30),DateCreated ,1)+' '+
       RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,DateCreated , 100), 7) AS time
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e913e/19)

Comment: The date its returning is in the format of JAN 14, 2015 not 1/14/2015

Answer (score 2):

Please use this query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(35),t1.DateCreated,109) FROM #tempTable t1
```

Referance: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp